# Usage of due to, being and given in the front of a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunctions, logic

I am writing a technical report and my idea is to say;

> Man-made objects have specific regular shapes, so that similar
>   property can be seen even from building roofs and roof corners.

As I feel the above expression doesn't have academic sound, I modify it as follows

> (1.) Due to the regularity of man-made objects, regular shapes can
>   also be seen from building roofs and roof corners.
>
> (2.) Given a regularity for man-made objects, regular shape can also
>   be seen from buildings roofs and roof corners.

I prefer to start the sentence with ***Given, Being*** as I saw texts in many text books do so. But now I feel, If I follow my 2nd option then it entirely change my idea. Actually I confuse now.

If you could suggest how my idea convert into academically sound manner, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me precisely what you are trying to say. What is the relevance of the specific viewpoints of roofs and roof corners? Would their visibility not be true from any other angle? Are the buildings designed with this in mind or is it purely coincidental? Are you comparing with irregular-shaped buildings or with natural objects (such as trees)? What is the overall context?

Comment: Your usage of due to and given are both fine, it's the rest that doesn't make sense. It seems you're saying a square building, viewed from above, would have equal sides and equal angles? I would not say man-made objects are typically regular shapes though.

Comment: @relaxing I rather agree with the idea of man-made objects being regular in shape. I agree with this line: [God does not build in straight lines.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/quotes?item=qt1788981)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between 'given' and 'due to'. It depends on where you want the emphasis:

A sentence structured as: 'due to **this**, **that** happens' puts the emphasis on **this**.
A sentence structured as 'given that **this** happens, **that** happens' puts the emphasis on **that**.

You can't really use 'being' here in any sophisticated way, so you should stick with the two new sentences you've written. As for which you choose; well, do you want the emphasis on the **regularity of man-made objects** or that **regular shapes can also be seen from buildings roofs and roof corners**?

This tip works generally; use it whenever you have something leading to something else in a sentence. :)

Comment: thank you for giving me a constructive comments. actually I want to emphasis the second phrase "regular shapes can also be seen from building roofs and roof corners". So then, what would be the best option.